Who should our Pro Tempore Moderators be?
We've just gone from private beta to public beta! Please vote for moderator candidates by voting on their answers below.
Because of this momentous occasion, I think it's time to ask our community who our Pro Tem moderators should be. From that blog post, I quote:

If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start
  one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the
  site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our
  choice.
This is the basic structure of a Moderator nomination thread:

The question should be community wiki.
Each nomination should be a
  separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta)
  so we can see their activity.
The nominee should indicate their
  acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the
  nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
Self
  nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had
  sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply
  a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links
  to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation,
  participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the
  site, etc.
Include the bullet points (from above) to show what we are
  looking for.


So with that said, who do we want to be moderators pro-tempore for this site?

How many Pro Tem moderators will there be?

@zergylord I believe we get 3

@BenBrocka I rolled back to Rev 4, because while the community input is extremely important in deciding who becomes Pro Tem Mods, it's not really an election. From Robert's blog post: About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who

Alright, that makes sense.

@BenBrocka After some discussion, we determined that CW makes sense after all, so I converted this question.

@AnnaLear was there a specific reason? since the change in CW rules (since anyone can edit with approval) I've never been 100% sure when CW is applicable

@Ben On the main sites, that's true - suggested edits remove the need for CW in most cases. However there are no suggested edits on metas (except MSO) so the idea here is for people who didn't self-nominate to be able to edit their acceptance (or lack thereof) into the nominations even if they don't yet have edit privileges. I'm not sure if that ever happens or if nominees are aware of it, but it doesn't hurt to enable the option.

@AnnaLear oh, I hadn't thought of that. I only recently learned meta sites don't have suggested edits. Why is that, because meta posts don't need to be edited for factual correctness or because they're not the "face" of the site so editing others posts isn't as encouraged?

@BenBrocka That, and because meta sites usually get less attention so suggested edits would be more likely to just be stuck in the edit queue limbo for a while.

I would like to humbly nominate myself.
I have been a Stack Exchange user for nearly three years, starting on Stack Overflow in early March of 2009. I am the Chief Technology Officer and co-owner of Digital Fruition, an internet software development company I founded in 2003. As a software developer I have always been fascinated by the workings of that amazing computer we call the Human mind, and I strive to learn and understand as much about psychology and related fields as I can.
I believe I have a number of important qualities which would enable me to be a good moderator of this site:

As a long time user of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange family of sites, I am very familiar with how things work, why the site is set up the way it is, and how a successful site  operates. I am active on a wide range of SE sites and have over 1,000 reputation on six different sites.
I am very active on Meta Stack Overflow, the "Mother Meta," where discussions about topics related to all Stack Exchange sites take place. Because of this I feel I have a very good understanding of how a Stack Exchange site should be moderated. I also have access to the 10K tools so I am somewhat familiar with the interface of the Mod tools. (Yes, I understand that the mod tools differ from the 10K tools, but they're similar)
I believe that I am a good leader, and my experience owning my own business and running the development side of a company shows that. I am responsible and I work well with others. I listen well and enjoy helping others. I have demonstrated these qualities on Meta Stack Overflow as well. As a moderator I will be able to better put those strengths to work by helping the community users in a way a normal user might not be able to.
I try very hard to be friendly, approachable and helpful. I truly enjoy helping people. I'd like to help newcomers to the site get up to speed and enjoy helping all users to understand how the system works and get better answers to their questions. One of our members already mentioned in chat that I had helped him early on. I quote: "you answered a few of my first meta questions. :) Guess you showed me the ropes a bit"
I am open to criticism and will not be upset or offended if someone disagrees with me. I have actively encouraged users to disagree with me here on Meta because I believe that it is only through (civil!) disagreement that some of the most important discussions can happen and the community can decide on our policies. If I were a Pro Tem moderator and the majority of the community disagrees with a decision I make, I will humbly apologize and reverse my position.
I am very community driven and believe that it is a moderator's duty to enforce the community's rules as decided and agreed upon on Meta. I believe this is especially true for a Pro Tem moderator, because we haven't had proper elections yet. As a nominator I will spend a large amount of time on Meta, helping the community decide what our rules should be and helping the community shape itself.
I am in front of my computer pretty much all day from 8:00 AM EST to at least 6:00 PM EST Monday - Friday (Because I am at work). While I'm not able to devote this entire time to moderation, I am able to use this time to check for flags and be available in chat for urgent issues, and will peruse the site looking for actionable items on my own while waiting for builds / long running  tasks to complete.
I believe one of the biggest assets I can bring to this community is my leadership and maintenance abilities. I may not have a masters degree in psychology, but I love to edit posts to improve grammar and formatting and help make questions clear. I know a good question when I see one, and I know a question that needs help. I believe as a moderator I will be able to give back to this community much more than as a regular user, because I will be able to handle flags, migrations, cleanup, and other "janitorial" work.
I am currently the site's top fourth fifth user, I am the most active in chat, I am currently the second most active voter and I am very active here on Meta with 7 questions and 8 answers. I really believe in this community and want to do all I can to help it grow and succeed!

I believe I understand the Stack Exchange Theory of Moderation very well. I'd like to be a leader of the community to assist the community in forming itself. I want to help start important discussions on meta and help enforce actions based on the consensus. I think I bring experience with the Stack Exchange model and a determination to make this site succeed.

+1 I think all of the above are great qualities for a moderator.

Thank you @JeromyAnglim!

I'm happy to nominate myself. 
My relevant experience:

COGSCI.SE: Active involvement in beta period of cogsci.SE on site and meta (here's my profile, I have the second most rep at the time of posting)
Prior Stack Exchange Experience: 12,000+ rep (3rd top) on Statistics Stack Exchange (my user profile on stats.se often answering questions related to data analysis in psychology)
Education: Undergraduate major with honours in psychology; Masters of Industrial / Organisational Psychology; PhD in psychology on mathematical models of learning curves
Work: Lecturer in psychology (2007-2010); Post-Doc (2012-)
I've been blogging about psychology and statistics for the last four years.
I'm also based in Australia which may have the benefit that I often log on at different times of the day to others.

In the end, I don't mind if I'm a moderator or not. I'm just keen for the site to be a success. Either way, I'm looking forward to contributing to the success of the site (e.g., lots of edits, votes, questions, answers, and meta discussion).

+1, you should add "creating extensive bullet point lists" to your bullet point list though. ;p

... and you should write up a blog post about CogSci. ;p

Thanks Steven; +1 for keeping me on my toes :-) I certainly will write up a blog post promoting the site. Let's start with a tweet and google plus post

I think your participation so far shows that you'd be a great candidate for moderator!

and finally, here's the blog post: http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/new-psychology-and-cognitive-science.html

I'll nominate myself. Here is my Cog Sci profile; I'm one of the top users of the site (the top user as of now). I've been using the Stack Exchange network for five months and I've learned the system pretty well. 
I've been mostly active on User Experience, Meta.SO and this site, earning 17,000 reputation total. I regularly participate in discussions of what questions are off topic on a given site, step in to help new users, edit posts and help improve the Stack Exchange communities I take part in.
I've got Bachelor's degrees in Psychology and Human Computer Interaction and I believe my experience in the Cognitive Sciences fields and with the Stack Exchange network make me an ideal temporary moderator.

I second this nomination! You forgot to mention that you're our #1 user, too... at least at this moment

I third your nomination; great ideas and participation on meta; excellent answers and many answers; proven track record on stack exchange network; active participation in chat and site related discussions.

I fourth it. How you managed to contribute so much in so little time boggles my mind :)

Might also be worth mentioning you often participate in chat. +1

+1 because of your contributions to UX. You'll be a great moderator.

I nominate Ofri Raviv as a moderator. He has a solid neuroscience background and his answers demonstrate that he's a got skills at explaining experiments. Besides, his neuroscience background will help a good representation in the pro tem moderators group. I believe a even representation is good there. Infact i started off looking for someone with good computational modeling experience but couldn't find one..
